# Is it possible to modify the date/time format for sendmail logs?

Tags: centos, sendmail, syslog

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

I'm cross-referencing logs with another application/server and would like to change the date format on the SendMail maillog.

Presently it's MMM DD HH:MM:SS

Is there any way to change that?  Where is it defined?

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to switch to syslog-ng to be able to change the date format in the log files. I don't think syslogd, which is the default in CentOS 5.x, allows you to change the date format.

Answer (score 1):

Syslog is the one responsible for sendmail logs....thus to change the format you'd have to change the syslog program.  Of course, that would change things for a number of other things doing logging.